# escaping mysql table not found

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that continuously  connects to a database and then truncates table in a loop fashion. The script breaks if there is not table found. How do i escape this to enable it run to the end?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 $username =$row['user_name'];
 $url=$row['url'];
 //$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
 $db = mysql_select_db("ghcomm") ;

mysql_query ("TRUNCATE settings") or die("error settings". mysql_error()); 
}
```

Comment: Check if the table exists before you truncate it, or don't `die()` on "error settings", just `continue`.

Comment: Unrelated, but you need to put your mysql_connect outside the loop.  You have a huge performance hit by connecting again and again to the same database.  In addition, the mysql_* functions have been deprecated in favor of mysqli, or much better, the PDO abstraction layer.

Comment: do you _really_ need mysql_connect() or mysql_select_db() on a while() loop ?! better remove it if not, because you are wasting precious resources.

Comment: This code is a mess. Filling $username but using $dbuser. Not using $conn. There also must be another mysql_connect outside the loop... this makes no sense to me.

Comment: thanks tony. taking a look into mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF EXISTS` in your SQL.

Just replace the last statement :

```
mysql_query ("TRUNCATE settings") or die("error settings". mysql_error());
```

with :

```
mysql_query ("TRUNCATE settings IF EXISTS settings") or die("error settings". mysql_error());
```

That way you never trigger the `die("error settings...")` part.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
or die("error settings". mysql_error());
```

to

```
break;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the new connection you create. Otherwise the connection from outside the loop will be used all the time:

```
$db = mysql_select_db("ghcomm", $conn);
mysql_query ("TRUNCATE settings IF EXISTS settings", $conn) or die("error settings". mysql_error($conn));
```

Comment: False, if no connection handle is specified, the mysql_*() calls use the LAST established connection automatically.